# access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission"...) with Java 8

Tags: java, security, sockets, applet

I have a Java Applet inserted on a simple HTML page:

```
<applet width="100%" height="100%" id="StatApplet" code="stat.applet.StatApplet.class" archive="stat.jar">
    <PARAM NAME="_cx" VALUE="25903">
    <PARAM NAME="_cy" VALUE="19738">
    <param name="frame" value="0">
    <param name="module" value="1">
    <param name="count" value="4">
    <param name="image" value="RSload.gif">
    <param name="boxbgcolor" value="#ffffff">
    <param name="boxmessage" value="Monitor loading">
</applet>
```

The applet is signed with a valid GlobalSign certificate.  The JAR and the HTML files are placed on an embedded web server at `http://192.168.0.91/`, a [Beck IPC SC143](http://www.beck-ipc.com/en/products/sc1x3/sc143.asp).  The applet opens a socket connection to the server it was loaded from:

```
try {
    final int CONNECT_ETHERNET_TIMEOUT_MS = 5000;
    final int PORT_STATUSMON = 945;

    String host = getCodeBase().getHost();  // get host address
    if (host.equals("")) {
        host = getParameter("host");    // to run applet from eclipse
    }
    InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(host);

    Socket ethernetSocket = new Socket();
    ethernetSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(inetAddress, PORT_STATUSMON), CONNECT_ETHERNET_TIMEOUT_MS);

    ethernetSocket.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

All worked well up to Java 7 Update 45, but after upgrading the VM to Java 8 Update 25 I get a security exception:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "192.168.0.91:945" "connect,resolve")
```

The exception is thrown at connect().  Isn't it true that an applet can do socket connections to the host it was loaded from?

Comment: Thanks, Holger, for pointing me to that thread (did not see it before).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your host name is provided `applet.getDocumentBase().getHost()`

if you try to connect to 127.0.0.1 but you are serving from 192.168.x.x or 10.0.0.x then you will get a `AccessControlException`

You should use relevant to this:

```
new Socket( applet. getDocumentBase (). getHost (), 4444 )
```

Comment: I'm connecting to 192.168.0.91, returned by getCodeBase().getHost(), getDocumentBase().getHost() does the same.